# Rounded Corner Crop Image Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, crop

Does anyone knows a library to crop an image to achieve a rounded corner output? I've found this https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/ but it only crops the image to cicrle.
I want to crop the image to this shape: http://harboarts.com/shirtdesigner/jpg_design_exports/square_rounded_corners%20_vector-graphic_1331986667453.jpg

Answer (score 1):

```
This example is near about what you are trying to achieve.
```

[cropper using jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/9r6czo65/12/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var c = $('.img-container img').cropper({ 
  aspectRatio:1/1,
  strict:true,
  background:false,
  guides:false,
  autoCropArea:0.6,
  rotatable:false,
  //using these just to stop box collapsing on itself
  minCropBoxWidth:50,
  minCropBoxHeight:50,

  crop: function(data){
      //console.log("data = %o", data);
      //console.log("this = %o", $(this));

      //test the new height/width
      if(data.height < 100 || data.width < 100){
          //try to make it stop 
          //$(this).cropper('disable');
      }else{
          var json = [
              '{"x":' + data.x,
              '"y":' + data.y,
              '"height":' + data.height,
              '"width":' + data.width + '}'
          ].join();
          $('#image-data').val(json);
      }
  }

}); // cropper

//console.log("C = %o", c);


$('.img-container img').on('dragmove.cropper', function (e) {
    console.log('dragmove.cropper');

    var $cropper = $(e.target);

    // Call getData() or getImageData() or getCanvasData() or
    // whatever fits your needs
    var data = $cropper.cropper('getCropBoxData');

    console.log("data = %o", data);

    // Analyze the result
    if (data.height <= 150 || data.width <= 150) {
        console.log("Minimum size reached!");

        // Stop resize
        return false;
    }

    // Continue resize
    return true;
}).on('dragstart.cropper', function (e) {
    console.log('dragstart.cropper');

    var $cropper = $(e.target);

    // Get the same data as above 
    var data = $cropper.cropper('getCropBoxData');

    // Modify the dimensions to quit from disabled mode
    if (data.height <= 150 || data.width <= 150) {
        data.width = 151;
        data.height = 151;

        $(e.target).cropper('setCropBoxData', data);
    }
});

}); // ready
```

style:

```
.img-container img {
width: 800px;
height: auto;
```

}

HTML:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script><script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/0.9.1/cropper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/0.9.1/cropper.min.css">
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="img-container"><img alt="Picture" src="http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/img/picture.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Please avoid posting "link-only"-answers. If your link dies, this answer will not help future users. Instead add the code to your answer. If you do so, having a link to a "visually working"-example is ok!

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve border radius like this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('button').click(function(e) {
        $('img').css({
            "border-radius": "10px",
            "-moz-border-radius": "10px",
            "-webkit-border-radius": "10px"
        });
    });
});
```

or 
you can use this library for border radius
[pie border radius](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Insider of complicating the code you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("img").addClass("important");
});
```

});

```
<style>
```

.important {
     border-radius: 100px;

}

```
<img src="/images/w3jquery.gif" alt="jQuery" width="100" height="100"><br><br>
```

Insert before

**Note**
1) You must keep the image as square then oly you can get the circle else u will get the eclipse kind of figure.